# Using UTF-8 characters directly

Tags: dvips, utf8

I've tried with:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03EC}{\`{\i}}
\begin{document}

Herman vonì\ Helmholtz

\end{document}
```

I got the error as  `Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.`

Please help how to print the character `ì` directly, I'm using `MikTeX V2.9`, `LaTeX`, `dvips`, and `PS2PDF`

Comment: Works for me with an up-to-date MikTeX installation. I don't even need the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03EC}{\`{\i}}`. Make sure your system is updated: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864. Are you sure your file is saved correctly as UTF-8 by your editor?

Comment: Not really to the point, but the ```\ ``` after the `ì` should not be needed here.

Comment: U+03EC is COPTIC CAPITAL LETTER SHIMA; you want U+00EC, but that's already predeclared.

Comment: `kpsewhich utf8enc.dfu` returns the path of the file that provides utf8 support. line 122 is \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EC}{\@tabacckludge`\i} which shows that backtick+i is already predeclared. U+03EC is something else, like egreg said.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your indication about `\ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted code runs without error (try copying it back from your question to a new file) but is more complicated than needed, you do not need `inputenc` or `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` or `\` 
(also as mentioned by others in comments you have a typo in the hex value for `ì` but that will not make an error)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Herman vonì Helmholtz

\end{document}
```

The error you show means your file is not in UTF-8, most likely, given the script you are using ISO 8859-1 (latin1) so you could add

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

But better would be to save the file as UTF-8 (most editors can do this).

We can not check your encoding as the act of pasting the text to this site converts it to UTF-8, so it is always UTF-8 here.

Comment: Your suggestion suits exactly with my requirement, thanks a ton